# Questions with favorite tags not showing

Tags: support, tag-watching, stackexchange.com

I'm having an odd problem with stackexchange.com.

I have quite a large number of favorite tags on Stack Overflow and questions with them are sometimes not showing on Stack Exchange. The picture below suggests that there are 19 questions, yet I'm seeing none and I can't believe there can be none new in hours. Clicking on `activity`, `newest`, `no answer` or `Favorite Tags` isn't helping. Logging off and then on isn't helping either. Is this some kind of a bug or is it me not understanding the grand idea of the website's user interface?

[image]

Using FireFox 15.0.1 on Windows 7 x64 if it matters.

Comment: Is this happening? It may have been a temporary outage in our tag service.

Comment: @Emmett It's been working alright for a while now. I don't know if it was just a coincidence that things started to fail when I added a bunch more tags into favorites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this appears to be working fine now, this was likely caused by a temporary outage in our tag service. We'll continue to keep an eye on this. Thanks for the report.